# Can't link to NFS mount from WSL2

Tags: windows-11, symbolic-link, nfs, wsl2

In an attempt to get round [Can't mount NFS from within WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04](https://superuser.com/questions/1772673/cant-mount-nfs-from-within-wsl2-ubuntu-22-04) I tried:

1. [Mounting the NFS share in Windows](https://ibexoft.com/mounting-nfs-share-on-windows-10-with-write-access/).
2. Creating a symbolic link from WSL2 to Windows.

The first step worked - I ran `mount 172.16.0.113:/mnt/share/yocto-cache z:`. It's read-only for now but I'll look at that later.

Unfortunately I can't get the second step to work. I looked at [WSL: Using A WSL symlink folder from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580420/wsl-using-a-wsl-symlink-folder-from-windows) but:

- From cmd (run as Administrator), `mklink /d \\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home\tom\cache z:\` failed with `The device does not support symbolic links.`
- From Powershell (run as Administrator), `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home\tom\cache" -Target "z:\"` fails with `New-Item: Symbolic links are not supported for the specified path.`
- From Powershell (run as Administrator), `cmd /c mklink /d \\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home\tom\cache z:\` fails with `The device does not support symbolic links.`

The second and third methods do result in the `\home\tom\cache` directory being created in WSL2 but that's it.

In an attempt to debug this further I tried symbolically linking within Windows. From Powershell (run as Administrator), `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "c:\yocto-cache" -Target "z:"` works and I can view C:\cache from WSL2 as /mnt/c/cache, but I don't seem to have permission to actually view it:

```
$ ll /mnt/c/cache
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom 7 May 24 16:19 /mnt/c/cache -> /mnt/z/
```

This may relate to [New-Item symlinks cannot be created if destination (target) is non-existent or not accessible](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9067)

Comment: Raised in Github as https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10132

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ln -s` in WSL?

Comment: @TomYan To do what? I can't see z: in /mnt/ from WSL2.

Comment: Well it seems that you can / need to mount network drive (letter) yourself: https://www.public-health.uiowa.edu/it/support/kb48568/

Comment: Turns out I can just do `sudo mount -t drvfs Z: /home/tom/cache` directly. Enter that as an answer and I'll upvote it.